# How do I change the max column width in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, psql

I have simple SQL query that selects a few rows from one table. One of the columns contains very long strings. I would like to set a maximum column width so that it is easier to read. I don't have access to environment variables through \pset.

Comment: Why not just call substring to limit the column's size?

Comment: For few rows there is `\x` meta-command. It makes more easy to see data with many fields/long values (if we are talking about `psql`).

Comment: Are you trying to truncate a long value to, say, 50 characters, or are you trying to *wrap* a long value to multiple 50 character lines?

Comment: I'm trying to wrap it to multiple lines

Comment: Why don't you use one of the many [GUI tools](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Community_Guide_to_PostgreSQL_GUI_Tools) for Postgres. Another option might be to use the `pspq` pager for psql: https://github.com/okbob/pspg